# How to put search option on data coming through web service..

Tags: android

I  want to put a search on listview with baseadapter where data is coming through webservice.

How can i do this ?

Comment: that is based on your need, it can be a "search" if the data will be dynamic based on the search Query in huge amount of data, or if the amount of data is lesser it would be "sort".

Comment: you want a search functionality in your listview??

Comment: Yes sir i want a search option in my list view where data is coming through webservice and i am using baseAdapter class for my listview